# How to use onchange function with a dynamic id that uses brackets

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php table created by a mysqli query where I want users to be able to update the date values of a text cell. For other formatting reasons, I have chosen not to use the date input.

My script works for other forms with an id that does not include brackets and changes the form value immediately and correctly.  However, when I apply the onchange function to the table cell, it seems the brackets in the id may be holding me up. I can see in the console that I am calling the correct bracketed id, however, nothing else happens.

Here is my cell:

```
<td>
    <input type='text' class='form-control form-control-sm' 
id='tbl_date01[".$tbl_ID."]' name='tbl_date01[".$tbl_ID."]' 
value='".$tbl_date01."' onchange=\"dateChange()\" required />
</td>
```

Here is my script:

```
function dateChange(){
    var id = (event.target.id);
    var y = document.getElementById(id).value;
    if(y === '?'){
        $("#"+id).val(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).substring(5,7) + '/' + new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).substring(8,10) + '/' + new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).substring(0,4));
    return;
    };
};
```

Comment: It's not the brackets its the quotation marks. what is the output for console.log(id) or console.log(y)

Comment: console.log(id) is tbl_date01[37] with the number 37 changing depending on the row of data I am looking to update. Console.log(y) is ? (question mark character). Thank you for any help! I am new to this. I should have mentioned that the table data is is all in a php echo.

Comment: now that you have console.log go and inspect the element on the browser and see what is the id on that

Comment: Thank you for your help! That is also showing tbl_date02[37] on inspection:      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="tbl_date02[37]" name="tbl_date02[37]" value="12/31/1969" onchange="dateChange()">

Comment: why is the console.log tbl_date01 and the inspect is tbl_date02?

Comment: My apologies, I was in the cell next to it.  They are both 01.

Comment: There is something wrong with quotation mark thats holding you up. I dont know what is.